layout in printing whith win.print()
I work whith nwjs, i generate a tickets and i want to print and generate pdf. But layout is not correct my ticket are cut between one page and the next at the end of page.
this is my print function, i used win.print(option) and passed the option bellow:
 print(printer) {
            document.querySelector('.btn').style.display="none";
            document.querySelector('.modal').style.display="none";
            var win = nw.Window.get();
            let pdfName= this.tickets[0].file;
            pdfName= pdfName.split(' ');
            let pdfname= pdfName[0]+'_'+pdfName[1]+'_'+pdfName[2]+'__'+pdfName[3];
            if (printer == 'pdf') {
                win.print({
                    autoprint: true,
                    headerFooterEnabled: true,
                    landscape: false,
                    shouldPrintBackgrounds: true,
                    pdf_path: 'C:/Users/STAR VISION_COM/Documents/out.pdf',
                    scalFactor: 100,
                    marginCustom: { "marginBtottom": 30, "marginTop": 20, "marginleft": 20, "marginRight": 20 },
                })
                this.goBack();
            } else {
                win.print({
                    autoprint: true,
                    headerFooterEnabled: true,
                    landscape: false,
                    shouldPrintBackgrounds: true,
                    printer: printer,
                    scalFactor: 100,
                    marginCustom: { "marginBtottom": 30, "marginTop": 20, "marginleft": 20, "marginRight": 20 },

                })
                this.goBack();
            }        
        },


You can produce a formatted pdf by generating and then distilling a post-script page.  You just have to develop a predefined post-script header and then append the data as a postscript array followed by an instruction (the instruction is defined in the header). The header can be designed to accommodate differences in the data between records (e.g. to add lines for longer addresses or change position of to accommodate longer larger space for preceding names etc).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
